# Virtualenv Pip installing to wrong folder

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I was working on an app with flask, and a virtual environment in the folder `/my/first/path/` to test out how virtualenv worked. Later, when I started actually working on my Flask project, I created another virtualenv instance in `/my/second/path/`.

Later, when working on my app, I realized I needed another package installed, so I executed the command `/my/second/path/virtual/Scripts/pip.exe install bcrypt`, which pip told me it successfully installed. Then, when I tried to execute my Flask script (using the command `/my/second/path/virtual/Scripts/python.exe app.py` from the directory of app.py), I got a python error saying that bcrypt wasn't a module.

Out of curiosity, I re-installed bcrypt (using the same command as above), and pip told me the module was installed to `/my/first/path/virtual/Scripts`. I tried uninstalling with pip and reinstalling as well, but it just did the same thing.

How do I get pip to install into the proper place? I'm worried that if I just delete the virtualenv instance in `/my/first/path/`, pip will just default back to my computer's instance of python, so I think there must be another way to install these modules.

Comment: Did you use command `which pip` to check the location of your pip?

Comment: I did that just now and got `/cygdrive/c/program files/python 35-32/Scripts/pip` (which is different from the other two paths mentioned above.)

Comment: Well, it looks strange. I guess you forget to activate your env. Try `. /path/to/first/env/bin/activate` first. And then use `which pip` again, if the path is correct, it should be `/path/to/first/env/bin/pip`.

Comment: After doing that, `which pip` still gives me the computer-installed version of pip, not the proper virtualenv. I tried deleting the other virtualenv, but now whenever I try to execute pip (even the one from my virutalenv) I get an error saying `Fatal error in launcher: unable to create process using ''''`.